Reduce Scenario consumption of Operations
I've recently developed a Workflow that download specific images from a specific topic from my job telegram group.
The first Module is a "Watch Updates".
The issue i'm facing is that EVERY message on the group is read by the bot as expected, but it is a waste of Operations because my Telegram group is VERY active. This specific topic is the opposite, is a topic created to upload to Google Drive and organize all images sent by every user in separated folders.
Is there any way that i can limit the Telegram Bot to watch a specific topic of this group?
I tried changing the first module to a "List Updates" but i wasn't able to make it work.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
